# Conversion from cubic catmull-rom spline to cubic b-spline

Tags: curve

I have a bunch of points that are the control vertices of a cubic catmull-rom spline. I would like to convert these to the control vertices of a cubic bspline.

I believe I can do this using this following relation:
$\boldsymbol{t} * \boldsymbol{B}_{\text{catmull}} * \boldsymbol{V}_{\text{catmull}} = \boldsymbol{t} * \boldsymbol{B}_{\text{bspline}} * \boldsymbol{V}_{\text{bspline}}$

where $\boldsymbol{B}$ is the basis matrix and $\boldsymbol{V}$ is a vector of the control vertices. To get the control vertices of the bspline, the formula just becomes:

$\boldsymbol{V}_{\text{bspline}} = \boldsymbol{B}^{-1}_{\text{bspline}} * \boldsymbol{B}_{\text{catmull}} * \boldsymbol{V}_{\text{catmull}}$

My question is once I process say 4 control vertices of the catmull rom spline, to get 4 vertices of the bspline, how do I process other vertices (i.e the order). If a catmull-rom spline has n-vertices with cubic segments, then we have at the most $n-3$ segments. So if we have say 5 vertices, $v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3$ gives us 4 vertices for bspline. How would I go about computing the other curve segment in the bspline?

Comment: Being pedantic, I guess you meant "uniform cubic b-spline".

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you asking, given a set of *N* CatRom cps, {CR0, CR1, CR2, CR3 ... CRn-1}  forming a piecewise curve, what is the equivalent *N* points, {B0,B1,B2...Bn-1} for a matching piecewise uniform cubic bspline?

Comment: Exactly. That is what I'm looking for. I think conversion to cubic bezier's are easy. But I would like to know if this is even possible/doable with bsplines.

Comment: I think it's a little trickier but I think there *may* be an approach. Still trying to work out the details.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the comments above for context:

> Just to confirm, are you asking, given a set of $N$ CatRom control points,
> $$\{CR_0, CR_1, CR_2, CR_3 ... CR_{n-1}\}$$
> forming a piecewise curve, what is the equivalent $N$ points, $$\{B_0,B_1,B_2...B_{n-1}\}$$ for a matching piecewise uniform cubic bspline?

> *Exactly. That is what I'm looking for. I think conversion to cubic bezier's are easy. But I would like to know if this is even possible/doable with bsplines*

I think it's a bit complicated: Using the approach you described above, i.e. $$ V_{targetformat} = M_{targetformat}^{-1} . M_{sourceformat}.V_{sourceformat}$$
you can easily go from a sequence of $n$ control points of Catmull-Rom to  $(n-3)$ *sets* of 4 Uniform BSpline control points, i.e. a *total* of $4n-12$ control points , but I can't see that this will allow you to stitch them together to obtain just $n$ points...

*Assuming* I've got the correct matrices for the 'typical' Catmull-Rom,
$$M_{CR}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 3 & -3 & 1\\
2 & -5 & 4 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
and uniform B-Spline:
$$M_{UB}=\frac{1}{6}\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 3 & -3 & 1\\
3 & -6 & 3 & 0 \\
-3 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
1 & 4 & 1 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
then $M^{-1}_{UB}.M_{CR}$ should be 
*[UPDATE: Fixed errors in coefficents]*
$$\frac{1}{6}\begin{bmatrix} 
7 & -4 & 5 & -2\\
-2 & 11 & -4 & 1 \\
1 & -4 & 11 & -2 \\
-4 & 13 & -26 & 11\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

It seems to me that, in any batch of four points, every output vertex thus depends on *every* input vertex, so it seems the neighbouring points can't be shared.

Having said this, I think perhaps there *might* be a way of getting an *approximate* solution (but I've not tried rendering it myself to check it so take with a grain of salt)

We know that a Catmull-Rom spline defined by $(CR_A, CR_B, CR_C, CR_D)$, passes through $CR_B$ and $CR_C$ at t=0 and t=1 respectively.

Similarly, using $\begin{bmatrix}t^3 & t^2 & t & 1\end{bmatrix}.M_{UB}$, we should see that at t=0 and t=1, a B-spline passes through $\frac{B_A + 4 B_B + B_C}{6}$ and $\frac{B_B + 4 B_C + B_D}{6}$.

First consider trying to go from BSpline to CR. If we had a 'loop' formed by N control points one would map from BSpline to CR with...
$$\begin{bmatrix}CR_0\\CR_1\\ ...\\CR_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = M_{NxBtoCR}.\begin{bmatrix}B_0\\B_1\\ ...\\B_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$$
where
$$
M_{NxBtoCR}= \frac{1}{6}.\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 1\\
1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 4 & 1 & ... & 0 & 0\\
: & : &   &   & ... & : & :\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 1 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If we invert that matrix to get $M_{NxBtoCR}^{-1}$, one should then be able to map the other way.

Using a maths package such as Maple, one finds that each row of $M_{NxBtoCR}^{-1}$ consists of the same set of values, all non-zero, which are progressively offset in each row. If we ignore the smaller terms, it suggests that $$B_i \approx 1.732 CR_i -0.464 (CR_{i-1}+CR_{i+1}) + 0.1243 (CR_{i-2}+CR_{i+2}) - 0.033(CR_{i-3}+CR_{i+3}) $$

There's probably some nice algebraic expression for this but I hope this might "do the trick".

*Update* Those weights don't *quite* sum to 1.0 - you'll need to normalise them slightly.

Obviously, this has assumed the curve is a loop. It's probably possible to adjust the weights for the end points but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Correcting M−1UB.MCR I've tested the matrices using renderings, the top right and bottom left values of the matrix are wrong, they should be negative.

Comment: My apologies.. I must have mistyped copying the values when I used Maple to do the calculations. The error is more than just signs!  Will fix ASAP